# Art des Vermögens on Foreign Residency Application

Tags: meaning

I am filling out an application for foreign residency in Austria. There is a section titled

> Verfügbare eigene Mittel zur Sicherung des Lebensunterhaltes für die Aufenthaltsdauer

and under that it says

> Vermögen, Einkommen and Art des Vermögens.

I am getting "Type of Asset" or "Type of Property" for Art des Vermögens in dictionaries online, but I don't own any property. My income is from a job. What are they asking me here?

Comment: Hello Joshua A, welcome on GermanSE! This question is more about law and institutions than about German language. Additionally, its Austrian bureaucracy, and I’m not sure whether there are significant differences between bureaucratic language in the Federal Republic of Germany and the Republic of Austria. Could you at least provide a screenshot of the form to help us help you?

Comment: @Philipp: There are great differences between the bureaucratic languages in Germany and Austria. In Austria we use a lot of terms in laws and other juristic documents, that are widely unknown in Germany.

Comment: You should ask this in the Expats SE, it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

You probably mean the form
[ANTRAG AUF ERTEILUNG EINES AUFENTHALTSTITELS

„ROT-WEISS-ROT - KARTE“](http://www.migration.gv.at/fileadmin/downloads/formulare/Rot_Weiss_Rot_Karte_Formular.pdf)

This form has 11 pages, and at the end of page 3 there is this section:

[image: Formular]

You are asked here about your assets and about your income. If you don't have any assets, then you leave this part free, or write »kein Vermögen«.

If you own a house for example, or a piece of land, then you write »Haus« or »Grundstück« under »Art des Vermögens«, and in the column »Höhe (EUR)« you write the value of this assest in Euro. Also stocks and any other forms of money your bank holds for you are assets.

Under *»Einkommen, geldwerte Ansprüche (insbes. Unterhaltsansprüche)«* you write the type of income, and in the right column you write how much you earn.

*Unterhalt* (maintenance, sustentation, funds for upkeep) is the money, that a divorced person gets from the former partner, and an *Anspruch* (right, claim) means, that a court has guaranteed you the right to get this money.

*Einkommen* is any income, for example the earnings you get from work, or the money you earn by selling fruits that grow on your fields, or just any other money you earn. (You surely know, that you can get the Rot-Weiß-Rot-Karte only if you earn enough money.)